# Problema con checkbox y listview

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, listview

Como hacer para que el checkbox se haga click si es 1 y se desmarque si hay 0 en un listview.?

```
public class AdminAcces extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userlist;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://192.168.0.101/dtbd/get_all_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "Usuario";
    private static final String TAG_DNI = "dni";
    private static final String TAG_NOMBRE = "nombre";
    private static final String TAG_Apellido = "apellido";
    private static final String TAG_ESTADO = "estado";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    ListView lista;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_acces);


        // Hashmap para el ListView
        userlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaUsuarios);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Antes de empezar el background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AdminAcces.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando Usuarios. Por favor espere...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * obteniendo todos los productos
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_empresas, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                //Log.i("ramiro", "produtos.length" + products.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String dni = c.getString(TAG_DNI);
                    String nombre = c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);
                    String apellido = c.getString(TAG_Apellido);
                    String estado = c.getString(TAG_ESTADO);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_DNI, dni);
                    map.put(TAG_NOMBRE, nombre);
                    map.put(TAG_Apellido, apellido);
                    map.put(TAG_ESTADO,estado);

                    userlist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AdminAcces.this,
                        userlist,
                        R.layout.vista_usuarios,
                        new String[] {
                                TAG_DNI,
                                TAG_NOMBRE,
                                TAG_Apellido,
                                TAG_ESTADO,
                        },
                        new int[] {
                                R.id.vistu_dni,
                                R.id.vistu_nombre,
                                R.id.vistu_apellido,
                                R.id.checkBox,
                        });
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Vista_Usuarios.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vistu_dni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:text="nombre"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vistu_nombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:text="nombre"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vistu_apellido"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:text="nombre"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

adminacces.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListaUsuarios"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" />
```

Al ejecutar el 1 y el 0 escribe el  atributo texto del checkbox y lo que se desae es que se marque si es 1, pero no se como hacer esto. He intentado de varias formas pero todas me arrojan error. ¿Cómo hago ésto?, saludos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código de tu adaptador para poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: Listo amigo ya agregue el resto del código

Comment: El adaptador que estas usando lo creaste tu?

Comment: no amigo lo adapte partiendo de un tutorial http://cursoandroidstudio.blogspot.com/2014/08/base-de-datos-remotas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente.

Primero ten en cuenta que un `CheckBox` recibe valores `booleanos` para mostrarse marcado, o no. Al pasarle un `String`, no se modifica la propiedad que marca el `CheckBox`, si no la propiedad que modifica el texto del `CheckBox`. Para que tu `checkBox` se marque o no, tienes que pasarle valores booleanos, no de tipo String.

Sabiendo eso, tienes que modificar el `HashMap` de tu `ArrayList` para que también acepte valores `booleanos`. Eso lo logras haciendo que los valores que recibe tu `HasMap` sean de tipo `Object`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> userlist;
```

Ahora bien, tienes que crear una variable booleana a la que se le asigne el valor `true` si obtienes un 1 del `json` y si obtienes un 0, le asignas el valor `false` (eso lo logras con un condicional). Esta variable es la que pasaras como parámetro al `HasMap map`.

```
// Con 'c.getString(TAG_ESTADO).equals("1")' evalúas el valor obtenido del
// json, si este es igual a 1, a la variable se le asigna el valor true, si
// es diferente a 1, se le asigna el valor false. 
boolean estado = c.getString(TAG_ESTADO).equals("1");

HasMap map = new HasMap();
...
map.put(TAG_ESTADO, estado);
```

Recuerda que al definir el valor del `HasMap` de tu `ArrayList` como tipo `Object`, este puede recibir valores de cualquier tipo, incluyendo `String` y `booleanos`.

Bien, en tu código se vería de la siguiente manera.

```
...

// Al ser de tipo Object el valor que recibe el HasMap
// este puede ser de cualquier tipo de dato
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> userlist;

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_acces);


    // Hashmap para el ListView
    userlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ...

}//fin onCreate


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ...

    /**
     * obteniendo todos los productos
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        ...

        try {

            ...

            if (success == 1) {

                ...

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String dni = c.getString(TAG_DNI);
                    String nombre = c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);
                    String apellido = c.getString(TAG_Apellido);

                    // Con 'c.getString(TAG_ESTADO).equals("1")' evaluas el valor obtenido del
                    // json, si este es igual a 1, a la variable se le asigna el valor true, si
                    // es diferente a 1, se le asigna el valor false.
                    boolean estado = c.getString(TAG_ESTADO),equals("1");

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_DNI, dni);
                    map.put(TAG_NOMBRE, nombre);
                    map.put(TAG_Apellido, apellido);
                    map.put(TAG_ESTADO,estado);

                    userlist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me sirvió mucho su ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado ;). Usted sabe, pa lante, la programacion es un proceso largo y tedioso.

Comment: Disculpe amigo, como haria para activar directamente el evento click del checkbox dentro del listview? , logre obtener el evento de la celda completa pero quisiera que al modificar el checkbox (solo el) activara un evento para realizar un update con los datos de la celda.